# Adapter for a function generator output

Tags: power-electronics, identification, semiconductors, adapter, function-generator

[image][image]

I want to order this adapter, but I can't find it on the web. Can anyone please confirm the exact name of this adapter for a function generator having a channel output and terminals for a DC power supply together?

Comment: Does the adapter inject power into the BNC cable, or does it just connect banana plugs in parallel with the BNC jacK?

Comment: Looks like two stacked adapters: a BNC T-piece and a BNC-dual-banana adapter

Comment: Please remove the adapter bundle from the instrument and shoot it so we can see the component parts.

Comment: The photos appear to show two different adaptors or combinations of adaptors - the first one has the BNC cable parallel to the panel, while the second photo has the BNC cable running at right angles to the panel.

Answer (score 0):

That is a standard BNC adapter.  The T arrangement is more common, but can cause cable congestion, block controls, etc.  You don't say what impedance you need.  Pomona and Cinch make both 50 ohm and 75 ohm versions.

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/coaxial-connector-rf-adapters/374?s=N4IgTCBcDaIEYDsDGACAhgEzQBwC4FMAnEAXQBoQBWKUbKARguzsnoAY2BfToA

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/pomona-electronics/6700/603407

Pasternack and Bowmar are other manufacturers that are huge in the adapter market.

Comment: no its not the one i am looking for. Its have just banana connectors but I want with banana connector and output channel port for function generator

Comment: I have added another picture of connector what i am looking for

Comment: what you are suggesting has BNC port at Input and Banana Connetors at output but what I am looking for is 50 ohm adapter with BNC port and bananconnector togather at output

Comment: Stackexchange encourages complete questions, **without** important bits buried in the comments.  Could you please _edit your question_ with this improved description.  Also, tell us as much as you can of the _function_ of the device, and try to give us a close-up photo, and possibly any markings.  As best as I can tell those "adapters" are either garden-variety BNC-T connectors plus garden-variety BNC to banana connectors, _or_ they are bias adapters.  But without a _clear description of the function_, or a picture of one of them after it's taken apart, we can't say.

Answer (score 0):

The adaptor that converts a BNC to a pair of 4mm "banana" plugs is sometimes called a **goalpost adaptor**. I suppose it looks like goal post from some angles!

Comment: what you are suggesting has BNC port at Input and Banana Connetors at output but what I am looking for is 50 ohm adapter with BNC port and bananconnector togather at output

Comment: Could you use a BNC T-piece and a goalpost adapter, combined? That's what the photos look like to me, although it's hard to tell for sure!